# библиотека Swing, создание окон

Tags: java, swing

Создается просто окно JFrame. Как сделать так, чтобы не было стандартной кнопки "развернуть на весь экран" ?

Comment: Стандартное `frame.setResizable(false);` не подойдет? Или именно скрыть надо?

Comment: необходимо именно скрыть, т.е. чтобы этой кнопки вообще не видно было

Comment: Если вам дали правильный ответ - проголосуйте за него\отметьте его верным ( серая галочка сбоку ответа). Это поможет другим понять, что ответ подошел для решения проблемы.

Answer (score 5):

Что-то особой информации нет. Есть вариант только убить дефолтную декорацию `setUndecorated(true);`, а затем добавить заново свою кастомную панель, кнопки и повесить на данные кнопки обработчики.

Вот код, попробовал пояснить комментариями, на сколько мог. Вроде все понятно.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

/**
 * Created by iprogrammer on 13.06.2016.
 */
public class Main extends JFrame {
    JPanel p;
    JMenuBar mb;
    JButton close, min;
    int pX,pY;

    public Main() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Custom look and feel
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Убиваем дефолтную декорацию (т.е. кнопки)
        setUndecorated(true);

        // Создаем Панель сверху
        mb = new JMenuBar();
        mb.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Создаем панель
        p = new JPanel();
        p.setOpaque(false);
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

        // Создаем кнопки
        close = new JButton("x");
        min = new JButton("-");

        // Обработчик кнопки минимизации
        min.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                setState(ICONIFIED); // Минимизация окна
            }
        });

        // Обработчик кнопки закрытия
        close.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.exit(0); // закрыть программу
            }
        });

        min.setFocusPainted(false);
        close.setFocusPainted(false);

        // Добавляем кнопки
        p.add(min);
        p.add(close);

        // Устанавливаем кнопки справа
        mb.add(p, BorderLayout.EAST);
        setJMenuBar(mb);


        /******** ЭТО ЧТОБ ПЕРЕТЯГИВАТЬ ОКНО (НАЧАЛО) ************/
        // Add mouse listener for JMenuBar mb
        mb.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
            {
                // берем координаты тыка и сохраняем их
                pX=me.getX();
                pY=me.getY();
            }
        });
        // Устанавливаем MouseMotionListener чтоб поймать перетягивание
        mb.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                setLocation(getLocation().x+me.getX()-pX,getLocation().y+me.getY()-pY);
            }
        });
        /******** ЭТО ЧТОБ ПЕРЕТЯГИВАТЬ ОКНО (КОНЕЦ) ************/


        // это просто надпись
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(40.0f));
        getContentPane().add(label);

        // Устанавливаем размер
        setSize(400,400);
        setVisible(true);
        //setShape(new java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D.Double(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),5,5));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

---

Получится что-то вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Остальное, я думаю, допилить сможете сами под себя.